# class hideed when I use Expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does the ItemCard class hides When I try to use the Expanded class?

```dart
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: products.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio:2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context,index) => ItemCard(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to put an image of ur problem

Answer (score 0):

> here's all the code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:feddah/homepage/products.dart';
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: products.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio:2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context,index) => ItemCard(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
    );
  }
}

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Products product;
  final Function press;
  const ItemCard({
    Key key, this.product, this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      height: 193,
                      width: 148,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: products[0].color,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      ),
                      child: Image.asset(products[0].image),
                    ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: Text(
                products[0].title,
                style: TextStyle(color:Color(0xFF122548)),
              ),
            ),
            Text("\$234",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can always edit your own question to provide the updates, no need to put it in answer section, as answer should be used to provide the answers only and not for elaborating questions

Answer (score 0):

Just add the shrinkWrap property to your GridView

```
GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a container after Expanded Widget. Also provide fixed width and height for the container. The issue might be the layout running out of usable space.

If still not working, check custom Scroll View widget

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/scrolling